# Does Frank iOS automation allows screen capture on real device?

Tags: ios, testing, cucumber, frank

Frank - Cucumber used for iOS app automation allows the user to capture the desktop screen in case of failed test case. This captures the screenshot of the simulator. But will it be possible to capture the screenshot of real device while running a frank test ?